# How check if pair of values exist in 2d Matlab array?

Tags: matlab

Say I have

```
a=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
```

If I then have x=3, y=7, how can I check that (3,7) exists in array `a` but also ensure that if I check for the pair x=3, y=8 (3,8), then it returns false and NOT true?

EDIT: (3,7) should return true but (3,8) false because 3 and 7 are in the same column, but 3 and 8 are not. Also (7,3) should be false because for `(x,y)`, `x`corresponds to element in 1st row and `y` in 2nd row

EDIT2: I see `isPresent = any(ismember(a.', [x y], 'rows'));` for the arrray `a`.

But what if I have this: `b=[1 5; 2 6; 3 7; 4 8]`. Then how can I ensure that (3,7) is true but (7,3) is false?

Comment: Why would `(3,8)` return false, because `(3,7)` was already found, because `3` and `8` are not in the same column, or something else?

Comment: because 3 and 8 are not in the same column

Comment: Examples with (3,7) and (7,3)  will be same for your case?

Comment: (3,7) should be true but (7,3) should be false

Comment: @user5739619 In the second example, `3` does not exist in the first row, nor does `7` exist in the second row. Please be explicit about the dimensions in which you are searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), but it works on rows instead of columns, so we'll need to transpose the matrix first:

```
x = 3;
y = 7;
a=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];

isPresent = any(ismember(a.', [x y], 'rows'));

>> isPresent
isPresent = 1
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But what if I have this: `b=[1 5; 2 6; 3 7; 4 8]`. Then how can I ensure that (3,7) is true but (7,3) is false?

Comment: don't transpose then